# Apple TV - How to download and installing "ipa" file?

Tags: ios, tvos, apple-tv

We're developing app on Apple TV and we develop under itune enterprise account and we don't use TestFlight we want download ".ipa" from web browser. This solution it's worked on iPad and iPhone but don't work on Apple TV.

We can't download ".ipa" file from our server and install on Apple TV, 
It don't have the browser for download link.

What is the best solution for resolve on this ?

Comment: Try this approach https://www.koditvbox.ca/how-to-install-apps-on-apple-tv-4k/

Comment: @Bmacin thanks you, but it's for developer ? becuase our customer don't have x-code and Mac. they only have Apple TV devices.

Answer (score 5):

To install Enterprise apps on an Apple TV you essentially have two options:

1. Install over USB or Wifi using Xcode - This is typically only used during development
2. Use the [Apple Configurator 2](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) tool

To use the configurator you must pair the Apple TV with your Mac much as you do for Xcode development:

1. Launch *Apple Configurator 2* and select *Paired Devices* from the *Apple Configurator 2* menu - This will launch the "Paired Devices" utility
2. On your Apple TV, go to *Settings->Remotes and Devices->Remote App and Devices
3. You should now see your Apple TV in the *Paired Devices* utility - Select *Pair* and enter the PIN shown on your Apple TV.
4. Once you have done this, the Apple TV should appear in *Apple Configurator 2*
5. Select it and then click on the "Add" Button
6. Select "Apps" and browse to your exported, signed enterprise .ipa file
7. The first time you run an app from your enterprise on a given Apple TV you will need to trust the enterprise just as you do on an iPhone or iPad.

A third option is to use an MDM; This is probably more applicable if you need to deploy to a large number of Apple TVs.

You can enrol an Apple TV using steps 1-4 above and then clicking "Prepare" rather than "Add" and provide your MDM server details.  You can also use Apple's Device Enrolment Program (DEP) to permanently link your Apple TV with your MDM.